# Find the interval on which $f$ is increasing if the **derivative** of $f$ is $f'(x)=(x+4)^6(x-3)^7(x-4)^6$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the interval on which $f$ is increasing if the **derivative** of $f$ is $f'(x)=(x+4)^6(x-3)^7(x-4)^6$.

Can anybody please verified that it increases at $(3,\infty)$, or do i have to do product rule with the above formula.

Please Help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: A (sufficiently nice) function is increasing if and only if its derivative is positive. Note that

$$(x + 4)^6 (x - 4)^6 \ge 0$$

for every $x$, and $$(x - 3)^7 > 0$$ if and only if $x > 3$.

Comment: You mean, "is increasing"?

Comment: @Alraxite Oops, yes. Thanks!